# Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle) Supported I/O Formats List

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I'm wondering where I can find an official list of supported I/O formats for Pentaho's Data Integration product.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any other resource but might as well check the wiki. Most of the I/O formats are listed as Input or Output in the Category column.

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Pentaho+Data+Integration+Steps

Too bad the Category column can't be sorted.